# Gradle cannot resolve transitive dependency, but direct dependency works

Tags: gradle, transitive-dependency, maven

I have a Gradle build script containing the following dependencies (and not much else):

```
dependencies {
    testCompile "com.foo:lib-foo:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
    testCompile "com.foo:lib-bar:2.0.2-SNAPSHOT"
}
```

The dependencies are resolved from a Maven repository (Sonatyp Nexus OSS). `lib-bar` has a dependency on `lib-foo` declared in its `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>lib-foo</artifactId>
    <version>[2.0.0-SNAPSHOT, 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT)</version>
</dependency>
```

When I remove the dependency on `lib-bar` from my build script (and all code that uses it), everything compiles fine. When the I declare dependency, Gradle complains:

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':testCompile'.
> Could not find any version that matches com.foo:lib-foo:[2.0.0-SNAPSHOT, 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT).
  Required by:
      :my-project:unspecified > com.foo:lib-bar:2.0.2-SNAPSHOT
```

The same scenario works fine with Maven.

The [tutorial](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html) does not mention any limitations on Gradles ability to handle transitive dependencies
or version ranges that would explain this, so I assumed this would work. Am I using it wrong? How can I make Gradle resolve that dependency?

P.S.:

When I run `gradle test --info` I get this:

```
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: https://nexus.foo.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/foo/lib-foo/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/lib-foo-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: https://nexus.foo.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/foo/lib-foo/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/lib-foo-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar]
```

These resources do indeed not exists, because the snapshots have file names with timestamps. But shouldn't Gradle use `maven-metadata.xml` to resolve that? And why does it work when I declare the dependency directly?

Comment: Since this is a public repository, please name the concrete dependencies.

Comment: It is not a public repository. It is only accessible from within my company, and the libraries involved are internal as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Peter provided useful insight and the final hint ([RTFM](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec%3ahow_to_declare_your_dependencies)), he did not post the solution, so here it comes:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile "com.foo:lib-foo:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
    testCompile("com.foo:lib-bar:2.0.2-SNAPSHOT") {
        transitive = false
    }
}
```

This tells Gradle to not resolve transitive dependencies for `lib-bar`. This works without modifications in this case because the only transitive dependency of `lib-bar` is already included.

Answer (score 2):

Gradle's support for version ranges is derived from Ivy's. I think what happens is that snapshots as bounds of version ranges aren't supported, and hence not recognized as such. As a consequence, Gradle tries to resolve `2.0.0-SNAPSHOT` and `3.0.0-SNAPSHOT` as static versions.

What's the meaning of version ranges with snapshot bounds? Will they match non-snapshot versions (e.g. `2.5`)? And what's the meaning of `[2.0.0, 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT)` then? I haven't seen this kind of version range defined or mentioned in any Maven documentation. If this does work consistently in recent Maven versions, you may want to file an improvement request over at http://forums.gradle.org.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! The version range uses snapshots because `[2.0.0, 3.0.0)` would include `3.0.0-SNAPSHOT`. If only one of the versions is a snapshot, and the other a release, Maven acts as if both were releases, giving that same, incorrect behavior.  We are using semantic versioning, and that relies on these version ranges.

Comment: So what exactly will `[2.0.0-SNAPSHOT, 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT)` match?

Comment: It matches anything from `2.0.0-SNAPSHOT` (including `2.0.0` release) to `2.X.X`, excluding anything with the major version 3 or above.

Comment: So you'd use it when you want the latest version in between these bounds, whether it's a snapshot or not?

Comment: Yes, exactly. (fill space)

Comment: So, the I guess the answer is, it doesn't work. Is there any way to tell Gradle to ignore what is in the POM and specify the dependency manually?

Comment: Yes. See the dependency management chapter in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html).

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVEN/Dependency+Mediation+and+Conflict+Resolution#DependencyMediationandConflictResolution-DependencyVersionRanges